# PKContact and Zip code for non US contries

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay, abperson

I am implementing apple pay for Canada, to know the location of user i should have his/her postal code to estimate shipping price.
I input

> H4A2R4

as my postal code as shipping address for ApplePay. when I am trying to get info from PKContact it just return me

> H4A

. how can i have it completely ?
my sample code :

```
- (NSString *)postCodeForContact:(PKContact *)contact {
  return contact.postalAdress.postalCode;
}
```

I also tried ABPersonRef and i got same result.

Answer (score 1):

Ali's answer is correct.
You have all needed info in

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                   didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                            completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus status))completion;
```

Just access it via `payment.shippingContact.postalAdress.postalCode` and if you want the user to know his shipping address is incorrect, then call `completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusInvalidShippingPostalAddress)` in the same method.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this change has been made by Apple. you only get the full postcode when users applies their thumbprint.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15217